# Boost с++ Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, boost

После установки буста 1.60 для vs15, и попытки добавить библиотеку

```
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
```

компилятор начал выдавать ошибки хотя я только добавил инклуд:

> 1)Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals
>
> 2)Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
>
> 3)Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)

Устанавливал по гайду [Сборка Boost в Visual Studio - Boost C++](http://www.cyberforum.ru/boost-cpp/thread1452872.html)

В проект добавил библиотеку вот так:

[image: компилятор]
[image: линкер]

Не могли бы вы подсказать что это за ерись?

Comment: если я все правильно понял, у вас проект собирается под 32 бита (Platform Active(Win32) ), а либы вы линковщику подсунули от 64 (lib64-msvc-14.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если я все правильно понял, у вас проект собирается под 32 бита (Platform Active(Win32) ), а либы вы линковщику подсунули от 64 (lib64-msvc-14.0)